# Coding tip - intersection types and java enums

Tags: java, generics, enums

Intersection types allow you to (kinda sorta) do enums that have an inheritance hierarchy. You can't inherit implementation, but you can delegate it to a helper class.

```
enum Foo1 implements Bar {}
enum Foo2 implements Bar {}

class HelperClass {
   static <T extends Enum<T> & Bar> void fooBar(T the enum) {}
}
```

This is useful when you have a number of different enums that implement some sort of pattern. For instance, a number of pairs of enums that have a parent-child relationship.

```
enum PrimaryColor {Red, Green, Blue;}
enum PastelColor {Pink, HotPink, Rockmelon, SkyBlue, BabyBlue;}

enum TransportMedium {Land, Sea, Air;}
enum Vehicle {Car, Truck, BigBoat, LittleBoat, JetFighter, HotAirBaloon;}
```

You can write generic methods that say "Ok, given an enum value thats a parent of some other enum values, what percentage of all the possible child enums of the child type have this particular parent value as their parent?", and have it all typesafe and done without casting. (eg: that "Sea" is 33% of all possible vehicles, and "Green" 20% of all possible Pastels).

The code look like this. Note in particular that the "leaf" classes themselves are quite neat - but the generic classes have declarations that are horribly ugly. That's ok: you only write them once. Once the generic classes are there, then using them is easy.

The helper class below just has some static methods. Other ways to go include

- providing an instance that returns a
  singleton, but typed according to the
  parent/child
- returning an instance
  for each paren/child, typed
  appropriately, and including one in
  each parent enum

With this second option, the "children" object would actually be inside the helper, so reducing the amount of code needed in the enumerations. They'd all instantiate a helper, and delegate anything difficult.

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class zz extends JComponent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PrimaryColor.Green + " " + ParentUtil.pctOf(PrimaryColor.Green) + "%");
        System.out.println(TransportMedium.Air + " " + ParentUtil.pctOf(TransportMedium.Air) + "%");
    }


}

interface Parent<P extends Enum<P> & Parent<P, C>, C extends Enum<C> & Child<P, C>> {
    Class<C> getChildClass();

    EnumSet<C> getChildren();
}

interface Child<P extends Enum<P> & Parent<P, C>, C extends Enum<C> & Child<P, C>> {
    Class<P> getParentClass();

    P getParent();
}

enum PrimaryColor implements Parent<PrimaryColor, PastelColor> {
    Red, Green, Blue;

    private EnumSet<PastelColor>    children;

    public Class<PastelColor> getChildClass() {
        return PastelColor.class;
    }

    public EnumSet<PastelColor> getChildren() {
        if(children == null) children=ParentUtil.loadChildrenOf(this);
        return children;
    }
}

enum PastelColor implements Child<PrimaryColor, PastelColor> {
    Pink(PrimaryColor.Red), HotPink(PrimaryColor.Red), //
    Rockmelon(PrimaryColor.Green), //
    SkyBlue(PrimaryColor.Blue), BabyBlue(PrimaryColor.Blue);

    final PrimaryColor  parent;

    private PastelColor(PrimaryColor parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Class<PrimaryColor> getParentClass() {
        return PrimaryColor.class;
    }

    public PrimaryColor getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}

enum TransportMedium implements Parent<TransportMedium, Vehicle> {
    Land, Sea, Air;

    private EnumSet<Vehicle>    children;

    public Class<Vehicle> getChildClass() {
        return Vehicle.class;
    }

    public EnumSet<Vehicle> getChildren() {
        if(children == null) children=ParentUtil.loadChildrenOf(this);
        return children;
    }
}

enum Vehicle implements Child<TransportMedium, Vehicle> {
    Car(TransportMedium.Land), Truck(TransportMedium.Land), //
    BigBoat(TransportMedium.Sea), LittleBoat(TransportMedium.Sea), //
    JetFighter(TransportMedium.Air), HotAirBaloon(TransportMedium.Air);

    private final TransportMedium   parent;

    private Vehicle(TransportMedium parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Class<TransportMedium> getParentClass() {
        return TransportMedium.class;
    }

    public TransportMedium getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}

class ParentUtil {
    private ParentUtil(){}
    static <P extends Enum<P> & Parent<P, C>, C extends Enum<C> & Child<P, C>> //
    float pctOf(P parent) {
        return (float) parent.getChildren().size() / //
                (float) EnumSet.allOf(parent.getChildClass()).size() //
                * 100f;
    }
    public static <P extends Enum<P> & Parent<P, C>, C extends Enum<C> & Child<P, C>> //
    EnumSet<C> loadChildrenOf(P p) {
        EnumSet<C> cc = EnumSet.noneOf(p.getChildClass());
        for(C c: EnumSet.allOf(p.getChildClass())) {
            if(c.getParent() == p) {
                cc.add(c);
            }
        }
        return cc;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question, but it may be worth re-phrasing into a question that you answer yourself so we can vote it up.

Comment: This isn't a question but I do think there is a place for sort of thing on SO. I know Jeff doesn't like the idea though so you might get flamed.

Comment: I have to agree with the previous comments, it would be much better to have this written up as a question (remember that you can answer your own questions).

Comment: I disagree that SO is the place for this sort of thing. This is really a blog post. If it can be written as a question, then write the question - if this is a good solution it will get voted up, if there is a better solution then it won't. -1 I'm afraid, and I'd vote to close if I could.

Comment: @Nick Fortescue Jeff said that he wanted to create SO as a place for people who weren't inclined to blog to share their knowledge.

Comment: @IainMH - I know, but for answers for questions. Jeff still writes blog posts. This one is pretty close to the borderline, but I think if the author can't rewrite as a question, then it ought to be closed. If it is what SO is meant for, it can be rephrased as a question

Comment: Is the question - what is the question?

Comment: Well, I don't block because I am just not cool enough to have something interesting to say every day. Or week. So I did this as a post.

Comment: This would be fine if worded as answer to a question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the Commons Enum implementation instead:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/enums/Enum.html

which allows you to create Enum's that can then be subclassed.

Comment: Real enums have benefits though, like ability to switch() on them.

Comment: real enums are also handles specially by java serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

this is simpler, does it do what you want?

```
import java.util.*;
interface Tree{
    Tree parent();
    Set<Tree> children();
}
enum PrimaryColor implements Tree {
    Red,Green,Blue;
    @Override public Tree parent() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override public Set<Tree> children() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(children);
    }
    final Set<Tree> children=new LinkedHashSet<Tree>();
}
enum PastelColor implements Tree {
    Pink(PrimaryColor.Red),HotPink(PrimaryColor.Red),Rockmelon(PrimaryColor.Green),SkyBlue(PrimaryColor.Blue),BabyBlue(PrimaryColor.Blue);
    PastelColor(final PrimaryColor primaryColor) {
        this.primaryColor=primaryColor;
        if (primaryColor!=null) primaryColor.children.add(this);
    }
    @Override public Tree parent() {
        return primaryColor;
    }
    @Override public Set<Tree> children() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    double percent() {
        return primaryColor.children().size()*100./EnumSet.allOf(super.getClass()).size();
    }
    private final PrimaryColor primaryColor;
}
public class Main{
    static double percent(final Tree tree) {
        final Tree parent=tree.parent();
        if (tree instanceof Enum) { return parent.children().size()*100./((Enum)tree).getClass().getEnumConstants().length; }
        else throw new RuntimeException("strange tree!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("one way");
        for(PastelColor pastelColor:PastelColor.values())
            System.out.println(pastelColor+" "+pastelColor.percent());
        System.out.println("another way");
        for(PastelColor pastelColor:PastelColor.values())
            System.out.println(pastelColor+" "+percent(pastelColor));
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is not having to cast things to Enum - to have it type-safe at compile time.