# Is there a way to declare an annotation attribute for *any* enum?

Tags: java, enums, annotations

At the moment I am developing an annotation-based binding-framework for Java Swing that uses [JGoodies Binding](http://www.jgoodies.com) under the hood. Unfortunately I am stuck with an annotation for a JRadioButton-binding.
What I want to do is specify a property-name of a model which holds a special value (enum). The radio-button shall be selected if this property has a specific value. Now I want to specify the value in the annotation like this:

```
@RadioButtonBinding(property = "selectedItem", selectedValue = MyEnum.FIRST)
JRadioButton firstButton

@RadioButtonBinding(property = "selectedItem", selectedValue = MyEnum.SECOND)
JRadioButton secondButton
```

However, I do not know how to declare the annotation to allow the above and **any** other enum, too. My first guess was this, but I learned that annotation attributes cannot be generic:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface RadioButtonBinding {

    /** The model-property to which the selected value is bound */
    String property();

    // Idea 1: Specifying the enum class and the enum constant as String - works but is not typesafe

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();

    String enumConstantName();

    // Idea 2: Directly specifying the enum constant - gives a compile-time error

    <T extends Enum<T>> T enumValue();

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: The RadioButtonBinding annotation listed here includes two ideas: The first one is to specify the Enum class and the String constant to use from it. But this is not typesafe of course and may lead to RuntimeExceptions.
The second one is to specify the value of an enum directly, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: btw I did a lot of this kind of stuff with JGoodies, one of the more miserable times I've had in Java.  The biggest problem is that he has a "base" class that most of his other classes extend and so his methods have signature like method(base,base,base), where the "base" class passed in must be a specific instance but the signature gives you no hint as to just what specific class it must be an instance of.  The bindings part was a good idea but he didn't suport it well at the time (years ago) and it was unfinished and only documented in german.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not going to work the way you want it to.  As you've found out, you can only use really plain return types in annotations.  Additionally, trying to get around these restrictions by doing stuff like abusing String isn't going to work because you need to be using a constant expression for initialising your annotation's values.

I think the closest you're going to get is to initialise with a String and then use code to compare with the enum's name().  But there goes your type safety...

Answer (score 1):

If your enums can implement all the same interface, you may find useful this question "[Coding tip - intersection types and java enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574529/coding-tip-intersection-types-and-java-enums)"

Comment: How exactly would you use that common interface in an annotation attribute? `<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> T enumValue();` doesn't work any better than without the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this exact same problem, and as far as I know, it can not be done.
It's a real bummer.

In my case, I wanted to specify @Version annotation, where any enumeration can be used, and enum values can be compared by ordinal (to find ordering of versions). Looks like I need to do what some other frameworks (like Guice I think) do and use doubles instead; bit ugly, but works ok for >= and <= checks.